# Way to use postgresql and avoid testunit by default in rails 3.2?

Tags: postgresql, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, rails-postgresql

I'm tired of typing `$ rails new [app name] -d postgresql --skip-test-unit` every time I start a new rails app.  I'm using rails 3.2.

Is there any way to make using postresql and skipping test unit my default for new rails apps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  Rails 3.2 makes setting those defaults easy by updating your `~/.railsrc` file.

At the command line:

```
$ echo -d postgresql -T > ~/.railsrc
```

Now every new rails app will use postgresql and avoid testunit.

```
$ rails new [my new app]
[my computer]:[my directory] [my name]$ rails new [my new app]
Using -d postgresql -T from /Users/benjaminunger/.railsrc
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
.
.
.
```

Any flag for the rails new generator can become a default by updating the ~/.railsrc file.